# How update my own app android?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to create a game for android, but this game will have a level. If I put my app in the Android Market how do I update this app after it's already been uploaded?

Comment: sorry MrEngineer13 if my english is poor, i try to write that you understand my question...

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide mechanism of saving user's data to a file or database, making user able to continue playing game from the point where he/she was before update. After that when you have a new release of the app signed with the same key and uploaded to the android play store, users will get a notification and will be able to download and update your app. Preinstalled PlayStore app on android devices will complete that task. Every time user starts your app check settings file and setup app's properties for the user for continue playing.

Answer (score 0):

You publish your apk via the [Developer Console](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/console.html).  You can upload unpublished drafts of your app without disturbing the published version.  Once you choose to publish an update, then the Google Play store will offer the update to your existing users.  Migrating your user's data is as described by [Maxim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323128/maxim).

You can sign up for a Google Play publisher account here: https://play.google.com/apps/publish